# How to create a new php file which uses wp's functions and wp's connection

Tags: php, wordpress, rest

I need to create a very simple REST API (GET ONLY BY NOW)
but tables for query are not native of wordpress then I need to create a new php file, 
this is not going to be a template
then how can I Access to wordpress functions and wordpress connection object for not create a new mysql connection object.

I tried but I got
 Call to a member function get_results() 
thanks

```
<?php
/**
* api
* @package accesspresslite
*/


define( 'SHORTINT',true);
require_once('./wp-load.php')

global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results('select email from wp_wysija_user',OBJECT);

?>
```

This is the path where wp-load.php file is.

[image]

and i got

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'global' (T_GLOBAL) in C:\xampp\htdocs\IniYuc\wp-content\themes\accesspress-lite-child\api.php on line 11
```

Answer (score 0):

You can load the wordpress functions/objects from outside the framework. Consider the following code:

```
define( 'SHORTINIT', true );
require_once(PATH_TO_YOUR_INSTALLATION . '/wp-load.php' );
```

Afterwards, alle the known objects (e.g. `$wpdb`) will be present.

Comment: where my file must to be saved? I actually have saved in http://mypage.com/wp-content/themes/accesspress-lite-child/api.php

Comment: Where you want, it is only import to specify the correct path to your wordpress folder.

Comment: I added my code but i got  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'global' (T_GLOBAL) in C:\xampp\htdocs\IniYuc\wp-content\themes\accesspress-lite-child\api.php on line 11

Comment: i added the code but i continue getting the same error

Comment: @angel Delete the global statement.

Answer (score -1):

Create a new php file in your THEME directory like:

```
wp-content/themes/accesspress-lite-child/NEW-FILE.php
```

And put the bellow lines at top of the file:

```
<?php
define( 'SHORTINIT', true );

//Add file from = C:\xampp\htdocs\IniYuc\
require_once('../../../wp-load.php' );
```

Note: set the proper path to wp-load.php so it loads the required file.

You can use WP functions now.

Comment: I have done but now i am getting Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'global' (T_GLOBAL) in C:\xampp\htdocs\IniYuc\wp-content\themes\accesspress-lite-child\api.php on line 11

Comment: How does this differ from the other answer 30 minutes earlier? Even the constant `PATH_TO_YOUR_INSTALLATION` is the same.

Comment: Note the file path, it should include the wp-load.php file from your ROOT directory of WP.